# Does the Black Knight satellite exist?

Tags: aliens, space

Is there an unidentified satellite, known as the Black Knight satellite, in a retrograde orbit around the Earth?

Comment: Is this a notable claim?  You should provide sources to prove that this claim is notable.

Comment: Why is this tagged as "life-expectancy"? Anyway, OP originally posted this on Space.SE, and the comments there include [a Wikipedia page on the Black Knight conspiracy theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Knight_satellite_conspiracy_theory), so I'd say this is notable enough.

Comment: @F1Krazy: Using the Wikipedia page as a notability reference makes the question rather silly, because it answers the question and because there is nothing there to suggest that this is still a serious contention in 2018.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) We have a rule that only widely-held beliefs are in scope for this site (or at least, claims made by notable people and organisations that are widely seen).  Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/883#883) to places where this claim is being made.

Comment: @Oddthinking - https://www.google.com/search?q=black+knight+satellite shows tons of links, so notability is not really an issue. (I agree that Wiki page may answer the question, but that's separate from notability)